# Lower case response from elastic search where as upper case is expected

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-map-reduce

I am trying to fetch data using elastic search with java using method
.addAggregation(terms(term))

The JSON response that I am expecting is 
{
    "key" : "TEST" 
}

but I am getting the response as
{
    "key" : "test" 
}
which is in lower case, I want the response to be as it is stored. Please help here

Comment: update your question with your mapping please: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your-index`

Comment: I guess it's more to do with the result data and the elastic search configurations, that I am getting the data response in the small case . rather than the way I query index isn't it?

Comment: Once I see your index settings it'll be clear :-)

Comment: There are certain settings in your index that could affect it

Comment: I am completely new to elasticsearch Can you please tell me where could I see those settings.

Comment: This is how I am forming the query, While normal curl call I am getting the
data in the correct case, But while appliying aggrigation to it, I am facing the issue 
.getClient().prepareSearch(index).setTypes(type).setQuery(matchAllQuery())
     .addAggregation(terms(term).field(field).size(0)).execute().actionGet();

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `key` is being analyzed e.g. lower-cased.

What you could do is have a "searchable" field that is being tokenized, but aggregate on a display field that preserves the casing. Or if you only want to aggregate (or if your search is case-sensitive and it seems for a field like `key` tokenization is also not desired) use the `keyword` type (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)

Comment: Could not make much with the comment, Can you give an example using the java APIs Please.